# Post raw text with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` and I am trying to perform raw post of text. When I look through the docs it appears that I can attach a dictionary of data but I cannot figure out how to pass raw text. The raw text I want to pass is:

```
{
 Email : "name@company.com"
 , Password : "password"
 , Accesskey : "long access key"
}
```

The sample code snippet I wanted to use is below. The problem is that I want to pass raw text and the example below expects an `NSDictionary` (parameters) whereas I simple want to pass a string.

```
       [client postPath:@"weather.php"
          parameters:parameters
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 self.weather = responseObject;
                 self.title = @"HTTP POST";
                 [self.tableView reloadData];
             }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
```

Comment: well.. i second the answer by ices_2.. but if you really want to use both the AFHTTPClient and want to add a post body, you could create an AFHTTPRequestOperation and enqueue it.. that might work..

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to do this? just post

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [parameters setObject:@"name@company.com" forKey:@"Email"];
    [parameters setObject:@"password" forKey:@"Password"];
    [parameters setObject:@"long access key" forKey:@"Accesskey"];
```

get on server(PHP) `print_r($_POST['Accesskey'])` 
will result - "long access key"

Comment: Lakesh, if I use the code in the format you requested it generates the following body text: "Email=name%40company%2Ecom&Password=password&Accesskey=long%20access%20key" but I need it to be in the format of "{Email:"name@company.com", Password:"password", Accesskey:"long access key"}". What I was is to just send raw text in the body. Should I be using a different encoding format?

Comment: I figured out the issue. The information was getting sent in the URL of the request when I needed it to get sent in the body. The code I added to do this is:     [client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];